# How post data to telegram from csv table with python?

Tags: parsing, google-bigquery, telegram, python-telegram-bot

How post data to telegram from csv table with python? Where I can save my dataset and how I should make query? I am beginner at Telegram APi. I tried to save my dataset to GoogleBigQuery, but query not work. Which service I should use?
My code

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import pandas_gbq
url = "https://ege.hse.ru/rating/2019/81031971/all/?rlist=&ptype=0&vuz-abiturients-budget-order=ge&vuz-abiturients-budget-val=10"
page = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

tbl = soup.find("table", {"id": "transparence_t"})

data_frame = pd.read_html(str(tbl))[0]
data_frame.columns=['Вуз','Качество приема на основании среднего балла ЕГЭ зачисленных на бюджетные места 2019','Рост/ падение 2019-2018','Количество студентов, зачисленных на бюджетные места','Из них: без экзаменов','Ср.балл рассчитан с вычетом баллов за И.Д.?']
data_frame.to_gbq('my_dataset.my_table', project_id='hseparser-261610', if_exists='fail', private_key='/Users/daniilorlov/Downloads/hseparser-261610-e5e26181b8be.json')
```

Comment: what exactly you mean by "csv table"?

Comment: csv table is my dataframe

Answer (score 1):

To understand the format of the API call you need to communicate with Telegram, I would suggest you to have a look at their documentation (https://core.telegram.org/bots/api).

Regarding your current issue, I just tried to run your code and It returned me an encoding error for the characters specified as column names. I changed them to english alphabet ones and removed spaces and special characters.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import pandas_gbq
url = "https://ege.hse.ru/rating/2019/81031971/all/?rlist=&ptype=0&vuz-abiturients-budget-order=ge&vuz-abiturie$
page = requests.get(url)



import pydata_google_auth
credentials = pydata_google_auth.get_user_credentials(
    ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform'],
)



soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

tbl = soup.find("table", {"id": "transparence_t"})

data_frame = pd.read_html(str(tbl))[0]
data_frame.columns=['FIRST_TENSE','SECOND_TENSE','THIRD_TENSE','FOURTH_TENSE','FIFTH_TENSE','SIXTH_TENSE']
data_frame.to_gbq('mynewdataset.mynewtable', project_id='myproject', if_exists='fail', credentials)
```

To authenticate I installed the pydata_google_auth library that uses the user credentials. Alternatively you can do it also through a Service Account as seems you were using a private key for your API call authentication, in this case the credentials variable can be specified as follow:

```
from google.oauth2 import service_account
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
    key_path,
    scopes=["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"],
)
```

(https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/authentication/service-account-file).

I did this in python 3.5 and I have been able to write to BigQuery through the library pandas_gbq. In the attached image my results...

[image: imported data]

Regarding the storage location of where to save these data depends on your need. BigQuery can be a good solution because it allow you to have structured data ready for telegram API calls, especially in case you may be having large datasets.

I hope this answer was helpful to you!